# How to apply group by on a property of type array using lodash or pure js

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, lodash

I need to group the data by sub categories, but the property is an array.

I'll appreciate your help, if there is any way to do it with lodash or pure js.

### Data Example

```js
const data = [
  { 
     title: "data 1",
     sub_categories:[{ id: 1, name: 'gold'},{ id: 2, name: 'water' }]
  },
  { 
     title: "data 2",
     sub_categories:[{ id: 2, name: 'water'}]
  },
 { 
     title: "data 3",
     sub_categories:[{ id: 1, name: 'gold'},{ id: 3, name: 'fire' }]
  },
 { 
     title: "data 4",
     sub_categories:[] // also can be empty
  }
]
```

### Code Example

```js
 _.chain(data)
  .groupBy(props => ) //need help here
  .map(({values, key}) => {
    return {
      values, 
      key
    }
  })
  .value();
```

### Expected output group by subcategory name (this would be a better solution)

```json
[
  {
    subcategory: "gold",
    list: [{title: "data 1"}, {title: "data: 3"}]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @NickParsons I just updated the content.

Comment: Why is it only `gold` that is in your expected output? What about the other subcategory values?

Comment: I only put gold as an example, to show the structure. But I know that all the data should be grouped by subcategories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a couple of steps, which you can combine together with `_.flow()`:

1. Create a new array by flat mapping `sub_categories`. This way we 'expand' the array to now include a `data` object for each subcatgory.
2. Group the flattened/expanded array by the `name` of the subcategory
3. Map the grouped object to your desired format with `_.map()`

```js
const data = [ { title: "data 1", sub_categories:[{ id: 1, name: 'gold'},{ id: 2, name: 'water' }] }, { title: "data 2", sub_categories:[{ id: 2, name: 'water'}] }, { title: "data 3", sub_categories:[{ id: 1, name: 'gold'},{ id: 3, name: 'fire' }] }, { title: "data 4", sub_categories:[] /* also can be empty */} ];

const grp = _.flow(
  arr => _.flatMap(arr, obj => _.map(obj.sub_categories, ({name}) => ({...obj, name}))),
  flattened => _.groupBy(flattened, 'name'),
  grpd => _.map(grpd, (arr, subcategory) => ({subcategory, list: _.map(arr, ({title}) => ({title}))}))
);

console.log(grp(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, especially using flow, I'll be looking at the documentation on this particular function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _ = require('lodash');

const data = [
    { 
       title: "data 1",
       sub_categories:[{ id: 1, name: 'gold'},{ id: 2, name: 'water' }]
    },
    { 
       title: "data 2",
       sub_categories:[{ id: 2, name: 'water'}]
    },
   { 
       title: "data 3",
       sub_categories:[{ id: 1, name: 'gold'},{ id: 3, name: 'fire' }]
    },
   { 
       title: "data 4",
       sub_categories:[] // also can be empty
    }
  ]
  
  g= _.groupBy(data.map(d=>d.sub_categories.map(s=>({"title":d.title, "name":s.name }))).flat(),"name")
  ans=[]
  for (const key in g){
    ans.push({"subcategory":key,"list": g[key].map(v=>({"title":v.title}))})
  }
  console.log(
     ans
  )
```

You can use above code to get the expected results. groupBy using loadash and other operations done using inbuild functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by nested values.

```js
const
    data = [{ title: "data 1", sub_categories: [{ id: 1, name: 'gold' }, { id: 2, name: 'water' }] }, { title: "data 2", sub_categories: [{ id: 2, name: 'water' }] }, { title: "data 3", sub_categories: [{ id: 1, name: 'gold' }, { id: 3, name: 'fire' }] }, { title: "data 4", sub_categories: [] }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { title, sub_categories }) => {
        sub_categories.forEach(({ name: subcategory }) => (r[subcategory] ??= { subcategory, list: []}).list.push({ title }));
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result)  ;
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```